# devexpress gridcontrol databinding from another thread

Tags: multithreading, devexpress

I have a devexpress gridcontrol in my main windows form which I want to populate its datasource depending on an event that occurs when my windows mobile phone is connected to the desktop pc via usb port(activesync). The problem is that the method called by the event is executing on an another thread. As soon as I assign my gridcontrol a new datasource, It attempts to redraw the control and at that point It gives me the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. I did my best to figure out whether it really is doing its job on a different thread since I did not created that new thread myself. Consequently, I came to the understanding that it really is since the thread that the method working on has different thread Id and even trying to make a small animation to be worked on the new thread to see if the the form gets locked while that endless animation running. So It is sure that I attempt to populate my devex gridcontrol from a different thread. How can I come over such situations not to get any reference issues.

I am developing this on a windows form project created on visual studio 2003 and relying on .net framework version of 1.1 and on windows 7 x86 o/s

Answer (score 0):

Devex controls have to be handled on the main UI thread.

Just invoke the method to work on the UI thread :)

Comment: Thank for the response :) But I need my method to be excuted after a specific event occurs. In my case, I need to populate the grid after I have connected my winmo device to the pc. Unluckily, that event is a piece of an assembly that I include in my project and using a different thread. Is there any workaround to solve this situation?

Comment: @Gorgeousyousuf - I'm probably missing something, but why don't you call a method in the Devex project and then use this.Invoke(del) to do respective action?

Comment: Don't think you missed something but sure that I missed something:) I didn't dive into such async operation much before. Just figured out how to get a method execute itself on a thread in which I want it to work on. Thanks for the responses E.T.